# "AWS: Deploy SAM application" not appearing in available commands

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, aws-toolkit

In VSCode I have installed the AWS Toolkit 1.62.0. I'm on Windows 11, and I do CNTL-SHIFT-P and type "deploy" or "sam app", no matches are found:
[image]

I was able to run "AWS: Create Lambda SAM Application" with no issues.

Is "deploy sam app" not included in AWS Toolkit?  I have closed and re-opened VSCode and same issue.

Answer (score 2):

AWS Deploy SAM is legacy functionality, I guess.
Use AWS Sync instead

VS code config
[image]

Comment: Okay, I'll check that out.  I was trying to follow a Udemy course, but it could be out of date.

Comment: You can paste images directly into stackoverflow and it will handle the links for you.  No need to upload to another site and then put the external link.

Answer (score 2):

I too faced this issue.
Problem: Option "AWS: Deploy SAM application" is missing in VS Code command palette despite of AWS Toolkit installation.

Solution:
In VS Code AWS toolkit explorer, I see directory structure (e.g., API Gateway, IOT, Lambda, S3 etc), right click and and pick 'Sync SAM application', ignore message 'The SAM CLI will use the AWS Lambda....', just click on Ok and follow instructions in VS Code command palette.

Note- You should have a S3 bucket created yourself before performing above action as you will be prompted to select a s3 bucket in command instructions.

Also wait for 1 minute to get the sync process completed.

It worked for me.